# How to access a variable defined in a struct

Tags: c++, struct, stdmap

```
struct POINT3DID 
{
    unsigned int newID;
    float x, y, z;
};

typedef std::map<unsigned int, POINT3DID> ID2POINT3DID;

ID2POINT3DID m_i2pt3idVertices;
```

Can someone please tell me how can I access the variables `x,y and z` using `m_i2pt3idVertices`

Comment: That is an ungodly use of Hungarian notation...

Comment: Thank you all for the responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ID2POINT3DID` is map container. You can access single element by some `unsigned int` key:

```
m_i2pt3idVertices[42].x
```

Or you can iterate over elements in container:

```
for(ID2POINT3DID::iterator it=m_i2pt3idVertices.begin();it!=m_i2pt3idVertices.end();++it) {
        cout << it->second.x << " " << it->second.y << " " << it->second.z << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`m_i2pt3idVertices` is a container for storing `POINT3DID` objects. Alone, it doesn't have member variables `x`, `y`, or `z`. You can put a `POINT3DID` inside of it though:

```
m_i2pt3idVertices[0] = POINT3DID(); // Put a POINT3DID into key 0

m_i2pt3idVertices[0].x = 1.0f; // Assign x for key 0
m_i2pt3idVertices[0].y = 2.0f; // Assign y for key 0
m_i2pt3idVertices[0].z = 3.0f; // Assign z for key 0
```

Comment: The first line (`m_i2pt3idVertices[0] = POINT3DID();`) is unnecessary.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yup, it is, I was just trying to emphasize the fact that `m_i2pt3idVertices` itself isn't a `POINT3DID`, but instead is a collection of `POINT3DID`s. Explicitly putting a `POINT3DID` into the collection was the clearest way I could think of illustrating that (but perhaps there's a clearer way I didn't think of).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use iterator. Here is a sample:

```
std::map<unsigned int, POINT3DID>::iterator it;
it = m_i2pt2idVertices.find(5);
it->second.x = 0;
it->second.y = 1;
it->second.z = 2;
```